# How to add Task on MSBuild argument command line

Tags: c#, msbuild, azure-devops, msbuild-task

I search how I can add custome task when I compile my project on VSTS without update my csproj, I have an dll with an Microsoft.Build.Utilities.Task, and I want execute it only when I compile on VSTS, because I dont want dependcies on this dll on my source code.

My dll is from a nuget package https://github.com/OWASP/SafeNuGet for validate package on build. But I dont want install this package on all my project.

Thanks

Comment: Not 100% sure what you're asking, but injecting custom tasks can be done by writing the task in a seperate project file like mycustomtask.proj then use `msbuild /path/to/project.csproj /p:CustomAfterMicrosoftCSharpTargets=/path/to/mycustomtask.proj`

Comment: So I need download external proj with my custome task on the build server and after call msbuild with your custome args. Thanks.